# Initialization of a class & memory leak

Tags: c++

Assuming I have this basic C++ class:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        void Foo() {m_a=0; m_b=0;}
        void Foo(int a, int b)
        {
            m_a=a;
            m_b=b;
        }

        void setA(int a) {m_a=a;}
        void setB(int b) {m_b=b;}

        static void init(int a, int b, Foo* foo)
        {
            if(foo) *foo = Foo(a, b);
        }

    private:
        int m_a;
        int m_b;
};
```

and in my main class I do:

```
int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Foo::init(1, 2, &f);
    Foo::init(1, 2, &f);
    Foo::init(1, 2, &f);
}
```

is there a memory leak in this program? Is it a good practice to initialize a class like that or is preferrable something like:

```
static void init(int a, int b, Foo* foo)
{
    if(foo){ foo->setA(a); foo->setB(b); }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile your code?

Comment: You aren't allocating anything dynamically (with `new` or `malloc`), so there's nothing to release (with `delete` or `free`). So, no leak.

Comment: What should leak here? I can't spot any single `new()`, nor any classes which would be using it indirectly.

Comment: Why not a simple `Foo f(1,2);`?

Comment: @Holt: I know that I could do `Foo f(1,2);` but I was wondering if that init was a leak.

Comment: @Svalorzen: I didn't try to compile it, I've written just the relevant functions and variables for my question

Comment: @ABCplus I'm telling you because it does not compile. The example you are making is wrong, as you cannot create `f` like you did in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is there a memory leak in this program?

No, there's no dynamic allocation, so nothing to leak.

> Is it a good practice to initialize a class like that

No, that's rather weird and confusing, and technically not initialisation at all (which is done when the variable is first declared), but reassignment. I'm surprised that it compiles, since there's no default constructor.

> or is preferrable something like

No, that's just as weird. Initialisation is done with the constructor:

```
Foo f(1,2);
```

and reassignment likewise

```
f = Foo(3,4);
```